# Visual C++ Unhandled exception.

Tags: c++, mfc

My project recently error occur as follow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I can't find solution.
This problem occur when is exit.

I am using third party library that is eXGem.ocx.
I think, this library root cause.

```
nRet = m_pXGem->Initialize(::GRES_GetFileDirObj().GetFile(GRES_STR_FILE_XGEM));
```

This problem occur when this code is run.

```
long CMainFrame::SetXGemHandle(CXGem *pXGem) {
long nRet = 0;

//edit by kimgh... 100330 //[[GEM]]
//CString str;
m_pXGem = pXGem;
if (pXGem != NULL) 
{
    //str = GRES_GetFileDirObj().GetExecutePath();
    //str += "XGEM.cfg";

    nRet = m_pXGem->Initialize(::GRES_GetFileDirObj().GetFile(GRES_STR_FILE_XGEM)); //str); //edit by kimgh... 090629...
    if (nRet == 0) 
    {
        ::GLOG_GetManager().LOG_Event(LOG_FLAG_XGEM, "XGEM::Initialize() = 0");

        nRet = m_pXGem->Start();
        ::GLOG_GetManager().LOG_Event(LOG_FLAG_XGEM, "XGEM::Start() = %d", nRet);
    }
    else
    {
        ::GLOG_GetManager().LOG_Event(LOG_FLAG_XGEM, "XGEM::Initialize() = Fail to read XGEM configuration (%d)", nRet);
    }
    getUnitManagerPtr()->GetXGem()->setXGemPtr(pXGem);

    ::GEM_GetVarManager().InitDataTable(pXGem);
    //GEM_GetAlarmManager().InitGemAlarm(pXGem);    //del by kimgh... 100330 [[GEM]]
}
return (short)nRet; }
```

Attached dump file is link as follow.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qamj8l4athj6ldu/HMId.dmp?dl=0

I don't know what is the actual problem is.
Please someone help men with this.

Regards.

Comment: You're trying to access an object that has already been destroyed resulting in undefined behavior. The value `feeefeee` is used by Microsoft to mark memory that has been freed.

Comment: More specifically, he's dereferencing a pointer that is itself a member of a free'd object, and that pointer points to a member 5 bytes into it's parent object.

Comment: You probably need to stop/deinitialize XGEM before exiting.  From the stack dumps, it looks like something in XGEM is trying to get the window title for a window that has already been destroyed.

Comment: If you have the associated source and debug symbols, you can load the dump file into Visual Studio and perform postmortem debugging.